# Can an application recognize whether it runs in a cloud or on a normal server?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

Can an application recognize whether it runs in a cloud or on a normal server?

If that is possible, I could automatically let the application deside wehere to store f.e. user pictures: IO or blob storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the **RoleManager.IsRoleManagerRunning** property.  This will be true if your app is running under Azure Fabric.  Note however, that this can be the development fabric (the fabric that is running on your development machine during your dev phase) or the actual Azure cloud fabric.